# Netbeans desktop application of teacher attendance

Tags: java, netbeans, frame

i use netbeans. i made a java project of making attendence by teacher. everything is ok. but the problem is when i maximize that application then all the textfield,label,button's sizes get disturb, means they are not in the right manner as i made in the netbeans. there size change automatically. plss HELP

its a netbeans project... see the code

```
public class about extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form about */
    public about() {
        initComponents();

    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/soft/36574_3587439778456_1199359522_n.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
        jLabel1.setAlignmentX(100);
        jLabel1.setAlignmentY(100);

        jLabel2.setText("Rajdeep Sinha");
        jLabel2.setAlignmentX(100);
        jLabel2.setAlignmentY(100);

        jLabel3.setText("B.tech  C.S.");
        jLabel3.setAlignmentX(100);
        jLabel3.setAlignmentY(100);

        jLabel4.setText("9621804097, 8687913559");
        jLabel4.setAlignmentX(100);
        jLabel4.setAlignmentY(100);

        jButton1.setText("Next-->");
        jButton1.setAlignmentX(100);
        jButton1.setAlignmentY(100);
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jButton1KeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/soft/ganesh-wallpapers-photos.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("jLabel5");
        jLabel5.setAlignmentX(100);
        jLabel5.setAlignmentY(100);
        jLabel5.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 255, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 138, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 279, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 131, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        p1 ll=new p1();
        ll.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(about.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(about.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(about.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(about.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new about().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *"NETBEANS DESKTOP JAVA APPLICATION OF TEACHERS ATTENDENCE"*  There is no need to SHOUT at us.

Comment: hahaha u r funny. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to add a LayoutManager to your window. NetBeans has support for it. Right-click inside your window in NetBeans, hover "Set Layout" and select a proper LayoutManager.

I always use GridBagLayout. Here is a tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Good Luck.

Comment: thanks but the link that u send me it is not using netbeans...i mean i already made a small project and i need to fix that.

Comment: *"the link that u send me it is not using netbeans"*  Any type of layout can be used in Netbeans.  Either learn how to use your IDE or *stop* using it and type code into a simple editor.

Comment: You can use the option "Personalize Layout" by right-clicking on your window.

Comment: @thompson. pls sir its a request dont comment if u dont want to help. you are de moralizing me

Comment: @GiovaniGuizzo   i did it but nothing happened. only in right side a side bar is shown and it was empty

Comment: @GiovaniGuizzo   i post the code :)

Comment: First set you layout as `GridBagLayout` through the NetBeans interface, and then you can personalize it.

Comment: *"dont comment if u dont want to help."*  Don't ask here if what you want a smiling tutor.  Pay a tutor enough and they will be as 'nice' as you like.  Ask a good question here, you will get a good answer - but it is not a social club.

Comment: its a very big question for me sirrrr....thats y i asked. if its a simple question then u should have answer it other wise you should ignore it.   @AndrewThompson

Comment: @GiovaniGuizzo   thanks a lot for giving me time and helping me.

Answer (score 0):

use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) it will resize your components automatically when you resize your window

check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for help

Comment: i have made 5 application like that. but it always resize the fram in wrong manner.

Comment: @user2096592 well in that case it would be better to post your code as well

Comment: they should change automatically

Comment: @user2096592 then suggested link and layout would work

Comment: can u correct my code if i send you. pls

Comment: @user2096592 correct?? you have already accepted an answer which somewhat shows that - that did solved you problem

Comment: its a very little project of 3 small pages

Comment: *"can u correct my code if i send you."*  Do not try to take things off-forum.  It is of no benefit to the community, and this is not the place to hire personal tutors or consutants.

Comment: i just made this id...i like the answer of u too...

Comment: @user2096592 feel free to post your code here and point your problem, we all will be happy to help you

Comment: @thompson  then for wat this forum is all about? i thought here people will help me. and i am really thankful for these people for replying me. you people have good knowledge so u should help. :)

Comment: *"then for wat this forum is all about?"* It is not a forum, but a Q&A site.  To learn more about it, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @bingo   thanks a lot :)    but how to send you my liitle netbean project ? pls help i am very new. REALLY SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH

Comment: @user2096592 just edit your above question and paste in your code there itself.

Comment: @Bingo   i did it. pls see

Comment: @bingo... where is the new code?

Comment: @user2096592 the code you have posted is netbeans auto-generated - though it is advised not to modify them. Now to answer your question - `javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);` you see these line of codes here you have set `GroupLayout` as layout whereas you need `GridBagLayout`

Comment: @user2096592 so right click inside your GUI window frame in netbeans and in `Set-layout` option choose `GridBagLayout` as layout

Comment: @Bingo   hmmm...so from now on before making any app on netbeans i have to choose GRIDBAGLAYOUT by right clicking on the FRAME??

Comment: @user2096592 NOT always - layouts are there for a purpose each layout serves their own purpose like in one case layout A will work good and in some other Layout B will

Comment: yup i choose now they are not automatically get resize in wrong manner. they just come in the center with there default size.  wat should i do if i want that if i maximize app then they should resize but in RIGHT manner.?

Comment: @Bingo   thanks a lot for giving me time and helping me.   my one last question in above comment. :)

Comment: @user2096592 oh well I see that was a good move - you just accepted an answer to get the work done. If this way you wanna look for help here, I guess you are in not in right place and none of the SO member will do so